# I need to scan a sentence and blank out a word that begins and is followed by "_" in java

Tags: java, string

For example, I construct a question like this:

```
FillInQuestion question=new FillInQuestion("The first president of the United States was _George Washington_")
```

And then I want my display method to blank out the answer so that the output shows

"The first president of the United States was ***_***"

How do I go about doing that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with regex.

`string.replaceAll("_.*_", "_")`

Comment: Thanks! I'm curious though.... can you explain the parameters? Specifically the "_.*_" part.

Comment: @user3736114 it is a regular expression. `.` means "any character" and `*` means "0 or more times". So `_` followed by any number of characters followed by a `_`.

Comment: That is a regex string. You can learn more about regex from the [Java Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) documentation or from the [Regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html). Google searching regex might also do you some good

Answer (score 0):

using regular expression:

```
public class Replace {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FillInQuestion question=new FillInQuestion("The first president of the United States was _George Washington_");
        String str = question.display();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

class FillInQuestion{
    String str;
    public FillInQuestion(String replace) {
        this.str=replace;
    }

    public String display() {
        str=str.replaceAll("_.*_", "_");
        return str;
    }    
}
```